# Retrieving an output variable from a deployment job

Tags: azure-pipelines

In the following example, I am able to access output variables of `jobA`, but not of `deploymentA`. The main difference being that `jobA` is a "normal" job and `deploymentA` is a deployment job.

```
jobs:
- deployment: deploymentA
  environment: Test
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - checkout: none
        - pwsh: |
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=someVar;isOutput=true]someValue"
          name: someName

- job: jobA
  steps:
  - checkout: none
  - pwsh: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=someVarA;isOutput=true]someValueA"
    name: someNameA

- job: jobB
  dependsOn: 
  - deploymentA
  - jobA

  variables:
    deployJobVar: $[dependencies.deploymentA.outputs['someName.someVar']]
    jobVar: $[dependencies.jobA.outputs['someNameA.someVarA']]

  steps:
  - checkout: none
  - pwsh: |
      echo "$(deployJobVar)"    # will display empty string
      echo "$(jobVar)"          # will display 'someValueA'
```

The [best hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable) I've found is:

> If you're setting a variable from a matrix or slice, then to reference the variable, you have to include the name of the job as well as the step when you access it from a downstream job.

Not exactly the same, but I tried prepending similar identifiers, but none of the following worked:

```
$[dependencies.deploymentA.outputs['runOnce.someName.someVar']]
$[dependencies.deploymentA.outputs['deploy.someName.someVar']]
$[dependencies.deploymentA.outputs['runOnce.deploy.someName.someVar']]
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax for accessing specific variables outputted from a deployment job? Alternately, does anyone know how to display all outputted variables?

Comment: Related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/4946)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The correct syntax for accessing specific variables outputted from a
>   deployment job?

It is correct you used about the syntax variable. For the caused reason about there's no value displayed in the next "normal" job, in fact you have mentioned previously, **it is a deployment job**.

In your YAML script, the variable `someVar` in the deployment job is created in job of release. This variable could not be passed out of stage, even though you set `isOutput=true`.(**Note**: This is only occurred in Release pipeline). It only exist in it current job if you just define it with `##vso[task.setvariable]`.

In release pipeline, the deployment job independent between each other. It means that if you define the variable in the task(eq. step), it could not be accessed out of the job. You can also test this with Classic editor.

If you want to use it in the other job, the work around is that you'd better store it in some storage like Key Vault. And then use it in the next job.

Comment: Thank you, that's unfortunate, but helpful nonetheless. But can you clarify what you mean when you speak of the Release pipeline? Since it is all YAML, isn't it all just Build pipelines? Also, why does this limitation exist?

Comment: @DanFriedman Earlier this year, we released a new feature which combined the build and release definitions all in one YAML file. It is convenient for users to configure the build and release both with YAML, instead of the release pipeline can only configure with UI previously. The deployment job you defined in the YAML, in fact, belong to release.

Comment: @DanFriedman As we know, deployment job is used to deploy. Different deploy independent each other completely. For one stage, it is a machine independently. In addition, you don’t need to specify the `checkout: none` additionally. For deployment job, checkout does not exist.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT, I don't understand. I'm trying to access an output variable from a deployment job in another deployment job. Both of these deployment jobs are in the same stage. Are you stating that `isOutput=true` is not supported in deployment jobs?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT If this is true, it needs to be explicitly stated in documentation. See this relevant [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/4946).

Comment: The deployment job is not independent of the other jobs. The `dependsOn` property works just fine. The problem is that deployments have a strategy step (like matrix) named `deploy` which introduces a prefix in the output variable name. Check out my answer for details.

Answer (score 5):

The docs are currently incomplete, but with a bit of imagination, we can notice that the second part of [Set a multi-job output variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable) applies.

all you need to do is reference your variable with the job name as a prefix: `deploymentA.someName.someVar` instead of `someName.someVar`:

```
deployJobVar: $[dependencies.deploymentA.outputs['deploymentA.someName.someVar']]
```

Yes, `deploymentA` appears twice.

Comment: I tried implementing this and it doesn't seem to work. See this [comment on GitHub Issues](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/4946#issuecomment-543319731).

Comment: @KrzysztofCzelusniak You are right! I updated the answer thanks to your tests. The prefix is actually the job name (in this case `deploymentA`), not just `develop` as I had previously stated.

Comment: Great! I'm confirming that the updated answer works for me and allows me to use a variable from one deployment job in another deployment job.